# How do I change the timeout for PHP ApaiIO Amazon library?

Tags: php, amazon-product-api, apai-io

How do I change the timeout for the Amazon product library PHP client? I searched the code for `timeout`, but it's not obvious how to pass a different timeout value.

https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=timeout

Comment: are you referring to the request timeout? that's not set in the library, it's set in your php configuration. you can use `set_time_limit(999);` to increase the timeout.... unless you meant like `sleep()` or something, it's not clear what you mean

Comment: Oh, I should have read the link first.. CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT is a constant from curl, you need to use `curl_setopt()` to change the curl timeout. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Yes, the request timeout. Yes, it _is_ set in the library. I provided a link to the class which uses it. Here is the full class: [Request](https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io/blob/4672fd47b9bdd575d782c1719ef32d74cb0a6f30/lib/ApaiIO/Request/Rest/Request.php). No, `set_time_limit()` is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you provided, there is no way to pass in a parameter for the timeout. You can see it's hardcoded right there in the constructor. However you can easily extend the class and re-write the constructor like this. Just call `eRequest` instead of `Request`.

You can see that `$options` is private, so you know it's not being edited elsewhere and a simple ctrl-f can tell you that it's not being changed anywhere else in that class, so these are your only options for changing it.

```
class eRequest extends Request{
   __construct(array $options = array(), $timeout=10){
        $this->options = array(
            self::USERAGENT          => "ApaiIO [" . ApaiIO::VERSION . "]",
            self::CONNECTION_TIMEOUT => $timeout,
            self::TIMEOUT            => $timeout,
            self::FOLLOW_LOCATION    => 1
        );
        $this->setOptions($options);
   } 
}
```

..Or if there are other parts of the library that use this, you will have to alter the actual source of the library.

Comment: The way the library [works](https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io#basic-usage), you actually call `new ApaiIO()->runOperation()`. It's not obvious how you can call `Request`.

Comment: I sort of guessed that much, being a cURL wrapper, that class isn't terribly useful on it's own. Why can't you just change that one line in the library code? That's by far the simplest solution.

Comment: I could, but it's included via Composer, and when it's deployed on Heroku, it's fetched from the main source, so my local changes are not checked into Git. `"require": {  "exeu/apai-io": "dev-master",`

Comment: ah, well i can definitely see your dilemma. the only other possible solution i could think of is some kind or really dirty hack where you dynamically rewrite the live code on the server.. but you don't wanna do that